# finding a fast way to calculate a nonce

Tags: hash, difficulty

I found a way for ultra-fast nonce calculation, based on my own method.
Does it makes sense to introduce such method, or the complex way of nonce calculation has some advantages?
Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because hypothetical scenarios like the presented tend to not have objective answers.

Answer (score 4):

The main value of the current approach of nonce calculation (brute force) is actually tied in very heavily with the value of bitcoin itself. In traditional currencies, if you managed to find a super easy way to mine insane amounts of gold without much effort, gold would quickly become worthless. Same idea.

Strictly speaking, the best tactic for you is to run it as a miner and see it in action. **If** it is a super fast method, i.e. if you have come across an approach to calculate the nonce efficiently instead of the usual approach of stumbling upon it, then you will make a LOT of money in the short term. If it's TOO fast, a smarter option would be to do it with a time lag so you don't give your game away and make your not-so-hard-earned bitcoins worthless. Once you have made enough money to keep yourself comfortable, offer your knowledge to a large fintech company in return for a significant amount of money or, even better, a career of a lifetime.

*At this point* I think it's important to state that many, many people try to find efficient ways of solving these problems. Many times people even convince themselves they have managed it. Each time it comes back to the same stumbling block (P vs NP). (E.g. one naive idea is to make the algorithm reversible via additional ancilla bits, but you'd need to iterate through all possible combinations of their end values in order to successfully reverse SHA256, and that works out as significantly more possibilities than there would be nonces. Been there, tried that).

If you sincerely have a working implementation, and you have tried it on historically known values in a blind fashion, then by all means start looking at colour schemes for your new private jet, and hairstyles for your Time magazine photoshoot. I say this in a dry, sarcastic manner, mainly because I have too much invested in bitcoin to want to see someone break it. As someone with a mathematical interest, it would definitely be staggering to witness though.